# Multiply Index pages using Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, indexing

I have used Joomla to create my website.

I need a disclaimer page to come up before the front end user can see the rest of the website.

I created a new "index.php" page with the disclaimer information, with a link to the site - I renamed the original php file to "index1.php

"Index.php" views but the link doesn't want to work.
My code does seem all correct.

Any advise please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just rename `index.php` in joomla. It's entry point to your website and it initializes/routes/runs your joomla app. So instead you should modify your `index.php` so that it recognizes 1st time visits and redirects users to correct page.

Name your terms page as `first-time.php` and modify `index.php` as follows:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['firsttime']))
{
    setcookie("firsttime", "no", /* EXPIRE */);
    header('Location: first-time.php');
    exit();
}
else
{
// Set flag that this is a parent file.
define('_JEXEC', 1);
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterLoad') : null;

// Instantiate the application.
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

// Initialise the application.
$app->initialise();

// Mark afterIntialise in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterInitialise') : null;

// Route the application.
$app->route();

// Mark afterRoute in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRoute') : null;

// Dispatch the application.
$app->dispatch();

// Mark afterDispatch in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterDispatch') : null;

// Render the application.
$app->render();

// Mark afterRender in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER->mark('afterRender') : null;
// Return the response.
echo $app;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hacking your website and making applying updates a problem have you considered creating it as a plugin?

As an alternative have you looked in the [Joomla! Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/)? It has a [User Management section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management) and on the first page of that I can see a Joomla! 2.5 plugin called [Terms of Service](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/19899) that might fit your needs.